# ubuntu don't understand that I install latex

Tags: xetex, installing, ubuntu

I install LaTeX from DVD in ubuntu and I don't get any problem, but when I type

```
xelatex
```

in terminal. I get this:

```
The program `xelatex` is currently not installed. You can install it by typing: sudo apt install texlive-xetex
```

[image]

what is the problem?

Comment: Hard to guess without access to your machine, but the most likely cause is that the command interpreter can't 'see' the latex binaries. Try doing `env | grep PATH` in the terminal. What is the result?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Where did you install xelatex? Is the folder part of your path?

Comment: PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

Comment: It looks like the folder containing the latex binaries has not been added to your path. Try closing the terminal and opening a new one. Does that fix the problem?

Comment: No. It doesn't help.

Comment: OK, you need to update the path manually. First find the folder containing the latex binaries. It might be something like `/usr/local/texlive/2017/bin`. Then add that to your path, and open another new terminal. Do `env | grep PATH` again to make sure the update has worked, and the problem should be fixed.

Comment: how must i add this address to my path?

Comment: [This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60218/how-to-add-a-directory-to-the-path) might help

Comment: typing `tlmgr conf` will output ample information and at top of it you can get definitive confirmation the PATH is correctly set-up for the texlive binaries to be found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open your home folder. Make hidden files visible. Find file .profile (note the dot in front) and open it in Gedit (the plain text editor).

Add this line at the bottom:

```
PATH="/home/owner/texlive/2017/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH"
```

The exact path may be different, depending on where you put texlive. The relevant folder will contain files (or hard links) such as pdftex.

Save. Reboot. EDIT: As noted below, instead of reboot simply log out, log in.

Comment: Reboot should not be necessary, just log out and in again. The profile file is read at login

Comment: The path could be `PATH="/usr/local/texlive/2020/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH"` in newer versions.